# Can x.509 and OAuth co-exist in one Spring application?

Tags: spring-security, oauth-2.0, x509

Is it possible to have a Spring application which authenticates some endpoints using OAuth2.0 (single-headed, a mix of password and client_credentials) while others are authenticated with x.509?  I can get either one working by themselves but not both at the same time.

With the configuration shown below, OAuth works as desired on /api-foo/v1 but blocks access to /api-bar/v1, even if a valid cert is sent.  If I put an @Order(1) annotation on the web security configuration, then x.509 authentication works as desired but OAuth stops working (for example when using password-based OAuth, the UserPrincipal is not set properly).

Am I doing something wrong or running into a limitation of Spring Security?

Here's my OAuth configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class OAuth2ServerConfiguration {

private static final String RESOURCE_ID = "restservice";

    @Configuration
    @EnableResourceServer
    protected static class ResourceServerConfiguration extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

        @Autowired
        private TokenStore tokenStore;

        @Override
        public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) {
            resources
                .resourceId(RESOURCE_ID)
                .tokenStore(tokenStore);
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                .sessionManagement()
                    .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .securityContext()
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/api-foo/v1/*").hasRole("ADMIN")
                    .antMatchers("/health").permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated();
        }

    }

    @Configuration
    @EnableAuthorizationServer
    protected static class AuthorizationServerConfiguration extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

        @Autowired
        @Qualifier("authenticationManagerBean")
        private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

        @Autowired
        private DataSource dataSource;

        private BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();

        @Bean
        public TokenStore tokenStore() {
            return new JdbcTokenStore(dataSource);
        }

        @Bean
        protected AuthorizationCodeServices authorizationCodeServices() {
            return new JdbcAuthorizationCodeServices(dataSource);
        }

        @Autowired
        private CustomUserDetailsService userDetailsService;

        @Override
        public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer security) throws Exception {
             super.configure(security);
             security.passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
            endpoints
                .tokenStore(this.tokenStore())
                .authenticationManager(this.authenticationManager)
                .authorizationCodeServices(authorizationCodeServices())
                .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
                .approvalStoreDisabled();
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
            clients
                .jdbc(dataSource)
                .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
        }

        @Bean
        @Primary
        public DefaultTokenServices tokenServices() {
            DefaultTokenServices tokenServices = new DefaultTokenServices();
            tokenServices.setSupportRefreshToken(true);
            tokenServices.setTokenStore(this.tokenStore());
            return tokenServices;
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my web security configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private CustomUserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        return authProvider;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(authProvider());
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/api-bar/v1/*").authenticated()
                .and()
                .x509().subjectPrincipalRegex("CN=(.*?),").userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
                .and()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .csrf().disable();
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }
}
```